# Error when fetching last months trending repositories in Swift 4.0 - Github API

Tags: ios, curl, github-api, swift4

I am translating the following curl to `Swift` but unfortunately I am getting the following error when running on PlayGround:

`` Optional(["errors": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x60c00000da70>({
    code = invalid;
    field = q;
    message = "\"`date\" is not a recognized date/time format. Please provide an ISO 8601 date/time value, such as YYYY-MM-DD.";
    resource = Search;
}), "documentation_url": https://developer.github.com/v3/search/, 
     "message": Validation Failed]) ``

This is the following cUrl,. It does work when executing it the Terminal.

`` curl -G https://api.github.com/search/repositories --data-urlencode "q=created:>`date -v-1m '+%Y-%m-%d'`" --data-urlencode "sort=stars" --data-urlencode "order=desc" -H "Accept: application/json" ``

This is my request:

```
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)

    guard var urlComponent = URLComponents(string: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories") else { return }
    let items = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: "created:>`date -v-1m '+%Y-%m-%d'`"),
        URLQueryItem(name: "sort", value: "stars"),
        URLQueryItem(name: "order", value: "desc")
    ]

    urlComponent.queryItems = items
    guard let url = urlComponent.url else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"


    // Headers
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    // Form URL-Encoded Body


    /* Start a new Task */
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            // Success
            let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        else {
            // Failure
            print("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
        }
    })
    task.resume()
    session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
```

Comment: did you found an answer?

Comment: Yes @PavelZagorskyy , see my answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cURL` runs a script on the terminal, hence, it passes the date -1m as the `q` parameter. For example, if the date of this answer is `2017-11-13`, `date -v-1m '+%Y-%m-%d'` will be `2017-10-13`

```
let items = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: "created:>2017-10-13"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "sort", value: "stars"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "order", value: "desc")
]
```